# PHP include local projects as dependencies

Tags: php, composer-php

I have two PHP projects A and B set up using composer. How do I include them as dependencies to project C.

I have tried it the following way, but I think it's not a recommended approach as path's are hardcoded

```
require_once 'pathtoA/autoload.php'
require_once 'pathtoB/autoload.php'
```

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap

Answer (score 0):

Within each project file there should be an individual namespace ([PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) ) declared to ensure names do not overlap.

file1:

```
<?php namespace foo;
  class Cat { 
    static function says() {echo 'meoow';}  } 
?>
```

file2:

```
<?php namespace bar;
  class Dog {
    static function says() {echo 'ruff';} } 
?>
```

To require the to files uses:

```
<?php
require('pathtoA/autoload.php');
require('pathtoB/autoload.php')'
?>
```

Comment: pathtoA and pathtoB changes from machine to machine. How do I have more generic solution. Just like the way how java applications treats dependencies as jar files , and jars can be maven dependencies.

Comment: Are they relative to the actual script file? If so you could use require('autoload.php'). If not you could provide the path as a $_GET just do injection checks on it. E.g. <?php $path = array($a => $_GET['a'], $b => $_GET['b']); require($a.'/autoload.php'); require($b.'/autoload.php'); ?> then run index.html?a=pathtoA&b=pathtoB